# React Router V4 use names instead of numbers in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes, react-router

I have followed a tutorial on [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf/) and it has helped me a lot to understand how the router works. But I have a problem with the URL it is generating. In the example that is in the blog post you can click on a player and it shows all the players information. The problem is is that it uses the number in the URL. I want it to use for example the players name instead of the number.

I have tried everything but it does not work.

This is the component where all the information about the selected player is shown:

```
const Player = (props) => {
    const player = PlayerAPI.get(
       parseInt(props.match.params.number, 10)
   )
   if (!player) {
     return <div>Sorry, but the player was not found</div>
   }
   return (
     <div>
       <h1>{player.name} (#{player.number})</h1>
       <h2>Position: {player.position}</h2>
       <Link to='/roster'>Back</Link>
     </div>
   )
 }

 export default Player
```

This is the code of the API where all the players are stored:

```
const PlayerAPI = {
 players: [
    { number: 1, name: "Ben Blocker", position: "G" },
    { number: 2, name: "Dave Defender", position: "D" },
    { number: 3, name: "Sam Sweeper", position: "D" },
    { number: 4, name: "Matt Midfielder", position: "M" },
    { number: 5, name: "William Winger", position: "M" },
    { number: 6, name: "Fillipe Forward", position: "F" }
  ],
  all: function() { return this.players},
  get: function(id) {
     const isPlayer = p => p.number === id
     return this.players.find(isPlayer)
   }
}

 export default PlayerAPI
```

This is the render code:

```
render((
   <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
   </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the component to show all the players:

```
const FullRoster = () => (
   <div>
     <ul>
       {
         PlayerAPI.all().map(p => (
           <li key={p.number}>
             <Link to={`/roster/${p.number}`}>{p.name}</Link>
           </li>
         ))
       }
     </ul>
   </div>
 )

 export default FullRoster
```

I have tried everything I could thing of but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. And if you want to see a working example of the full code please have a look at the blog post via the link above. I can't paste all the code from the blog post here.

Kind regards.

Comment: Could You submit the code where You write the specific router for player page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without to know exactly how is write the router. 
First the Link You need to change:

```
<Link to={`/roster/${p.number}`}>{p.name}</Link>
// To
const name = p.name.replace(" ", "-"); // replace all empty characters with - 
<Link to={`/roster/${name}`}>{p.name}</Link>
```

In the router the parameter will be p.name. And more readable, You need to change the router

I find something on tutorial like:

```
<Route exact path='/roster' component={FullRoster}/>
<Route path='/roster/:number' component={Player}/>
// To
<Route exact path='/roster' component={FullRoster}/>
<Route path='/roster/:name' component={Player}/>
```

***UPDATE***

**Component**

```
    const Player = (props) => {
    const player = PlayerAPI.get(
       props.match.params.name.replace("-", " ");
   )
   if (!player) {
     return <div>Sorry, but the player was not found</div>
   }
   return (
     <div>
       <h1>{player.name} (#{player.number})</h1>
       <h2>Position: {player.position}</h2>
       <Link to='/roster'>Back</Link>
     </div>
   )
 }

 export default Player
```

**API**

```
    const PlayerAPI = {
 players: [
    { number: 1, name: "Ben Blocker", position: "G" },
    { number: 2, name: "Dave Defender", position: "D" },
    { number: 3, name: "Sam Sweeper", position: "D" },
    { number: 4, name: "Matt Midfielder", position: "M" },
    { number: 5, name: "William Winger", position: "M" },
    { number: 6, name: "Fillipe Forward", position: "F" }
  ],
  all: function() { return this.players},
  get: function(name) {
     const isPlayer = p => p.name === name
     return this.players.find(isPlayer)
   }
}

 export default PlayerAPI
```

**Full Roster**

```
    const FullRoster = () => (
   <div>
     <ul>
       {
         PlayerAPI.all().map(p => () => {
            const name = p.name.replace(" ", "-");
            return (
                <li key={p.name}>
                  <Link to={`/roster/${name}`}>{p.name}</Link>
                </li>
            )
         })
       }
     </ul>
   </div>
 )

 export default FullRoster
```

**NOTE** I see the players is have only two names for that is possible to used replace(" ", "-"). If is have more names then is need use regex for can replace every space on the name with minus

Comment: When you have done the above you will need to change `parseInt(props.match.params.number, 10)` to `parseInt(props.match.params.name, 10)` in the `Player` component

Comment: User should also encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent() on the Player.name as it will contain spaces and other special characters

Comment: Change my answer,